# In edit page show selected radio button

Tags: php, mysql

On my edit pages, how would I show the correct radio button if for $subscribedrips is equal to Yes or No? Here is what I have and its not working:

```
 if ($row['subscribedrips'] == Yes) { 
  echo 
  '<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="Yes" CHECKED /> Yes 
  <input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="No" /> No';
  }
  elseif ($row['subscribedrips'] == No) {
  echo 
  '<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="Yes" /> Yes 
  <input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="No" CHECKED/> No';
  }
  elseif (empty($row['subscribedrips'])) {
  echo 
  '<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="Yes" CHECKED/> Yes 
  <input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="No" /> No';
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
printf('<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="Yes" %s /> Yes'."\n", 
    ($subscribedrips == 'Yes' ? 'CHECKED' : ''));
printf('<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="No" %s /> No'."\n",   
    ($subscribedrips == 'No'  ? 'CHECKED' : ''));
```

works.  It uses the ternary operator to either insert `'CHECKED'` or an empty string into the input tag, based on the value of `$subscribedrips`.

You could also do in a more verbose manner, for example with switch:

```
$sel_y = '';
$sel_n = '';
switch($subscribedrips)
{
    case 'Yes':
        $sel_y = 'CHECKED';
        break;
    case 'No':
        $sel_n = 'CHECKED';
        break;
    default:
        // Neither need to be changed, so we dont even need this branch
        break;
}

printf('<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="Yes" %s /> Yes'."\n", $sel_y);
printf('<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="No" %s /> No'."\n",   $sel_n);
```

Personal preference really.

---

***Updated Snippet 1***

```
printf('<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="Yes" %s /> Yes'."\n", 
    ((array_key_exists('subscribedrips', $row) && $row['subscribedrips'] == 'Yes') ? 'CHECKED' : ''));
printf('<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="No" %s /> No'."\n",   
    ((array_key_exists('subscribedrips', $row) && $row['subscribedrips'] == 'No')  ? 'CHECKED' : ''));
```

***Updated Snippet 2***

```
$sel_y = '';
$sel_n = '';
if(array_key_exists('subscribedrips', $row))
{
    switch($row['subscribedrips'])
    {
        case 'Yes':
            $sel_y = 'CHECKED';
            break;
        case 'No':
            $sel_n = 'CHECKED';
            break;
        default:
            // Neither need to be changed, so we dont even need this branch
            break;
    }
}

printf('<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="Yes" %s /> Yes'."\n", $sel_y);
printf('<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="No" %s /> No'."\n",   $sel_n);
```

---

Regarding your last question, the difference between our approaches is pretty simple, but once again (ahh!) its a style choice, both accomplish the same goal, both methods are used in "production" PHP code.

My example builds the entire input tag in PHP and prints it.  Valentinas' approach pulls the static text out of the PHP strings and puts it directly into HTML.

For example, the following lines will all result in the same output:

```
<?php printf("<strong>%s</strong>", $some_string); ?>

<?php echo "<strong>$some_string</strong>"; ?>

<?php echo "<strong>".$some_string."</strong>"; ?>

<strong><?php echo $some_string; ?></strong>
```

I'm doubtful there is any significant performance difference between the two methods, but there is one cosmetic differences that I'll highlight.

- **Syntax highlighting** - If you use an editor with syntax highlighting, valentinas' approach will allow the syntax highlighter to appropriately highlight the `input` tag and its attributes.  Using my approach, the entire string would be highlighted the same.  [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV4Nx.png) showing how notepad++ highlights the two methods.

  As you can see valentinas' approach results in a more colorful display, which could help identify and track down errors.

There are some subtle differences when it comes to how your code has to be formatted if you want to conditionally print the entire tag, but they're not really worth talking about -- the biggest, in my opinion, is the syntax highlighting.

Comment: hmmm..this doesn't check the correct radio button, No is check when Yes should be. `printf('<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="Yes" %s /> Yes'."\n", 
    ($subscribedrips == 'Yes' ? 'CHECKED' : ''));
printf('<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="No" %s /> No'."\n",   
    ($subscribedrips == 'No'  ? 'CHECKED' : ''));
`

Comment: @Josh, are you sure? It works for me.  Can you post all your code?

Comment: What is the difference between doing it this way and the way valentinas did it? I'm trying to learn!

Comment: That too is personal preference.  My justification for using `printf` is threefold: (1) I'm not a fan of the `"$var"` automatically expanding when `$var` is a defined variable but it remaining as the string `"$var"` when its not.  So I never include variables in strings that way.  (2) The other way (`'stringprefix'.$var.'suffix'`) often requires some messyness with single quotes and periods, not to mention the times when double quotes and escaped quotes also enter this mix.   (3) My string is generally all in once place, not split up into a million different pieces separated by expressions.

Comment: `echo` is by no means old school and from what I can tell its more popular than `printf`, but having "grown up" programming in C, I have a special place in my heart for the function that just works.

Comment: Great explaination, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be missing "" near the value?

```
if ($subscribedrips == "Yes") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
<?php $subscribedrips = $row['subscribedrips']; ?>
<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="Yes" <?php echo ($subscribedrips == 'Yes') ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>/> Yes 
<input type="radio" name="subscribedrips" value="No" <?php echo ($subscribedrips == 'No') ? "checked" : "" ;  ?>/> No
```

I like taking markup out of PHP tags - makes it more readable.

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference between doing it this way and the way jedwards did it? I'm learning!

Comment: Main difference is that in my example most IDEs will highlight both: HTML and PHP. in jedwards example HTML is trapped inside a PHP string and there's no syntax highlighting for it.

Answer (score 0):

all the codes which are presented above will work but they look like big or no.of line are more, may be there is nice way if we use like above 
i have a better and simple way to show the value of the radio button in the page

code in add form:

```
<td>Gender</td>
              <td><input type="radio" name="emp_gender" id="emp_gender" value="M" />Male
              <input type="radio" name="emp_gender" id="emp_gender" value="F" />Female</td>
```

now if you want to edit the field of gender then you have to bring the previously selected value

to do this my code is

```
<td>Gender</td>
              <td><input type="radio" name="emp_gender" id="emp_gender" value="M" <?php echo ($emp_gender == 'M')? "CHECKED" : " " ?> />Male
              <input type="radio" name="emp_gender" id="emp_gender" value="F" <?php echo ($emp_gender == 'F')? "CHECKED" : " " ?> />Female</td>
```

above bolded lines are important in bringing the value of the radio button to the edit form