# How to get checked radio button in edit page in php?

Tags: php

In php form I get the data from radio button to database. It works well. But in edit page how do I get the checked value from database?

```
 <td align="left" valign="middle"><input name="signi" type="radio" id="signi" value="S"/> YES
  <input name="signi" type="radio" id="signi" value="N" /> No</td></td>
```

Comment: How are you getting the other details on edit page?

Comment: Read on: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm  it's an HTML question, just a matter of `echo`'ing the 'checked' before you close the input.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do like this in your edit page:

Take database value in variable:

Example:

```
<?php $signi= $row['signi']; ?>
```

And :

```
<td align="left" valign="middle">
<input name="signi" type="radio" id="signi" value="S" <?php echo ($signi== 'Yes') ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>/> YES
<input name="signi" type="radio" id="signi" value="N" <?php echo ($signi== 'No') ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>/> No</td></td>
```

Check this thread for details:

[In edit page show selected radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218207/in-edit-page-show-selected-radio-button)

Comment: Thanks.... But its work well when  <?php $signi= $row['signi']; ?>
    <input name="signi" type="radio" id="signi" value="S" <?php echo ($signi== 'S') ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>/> YES
   <?php $signi= $row['signi']; ?> 
<input name="signi" type="radio" id="signi" value="N" <?php echo ($signi== 'N') ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>/>No

Answer (score 1):

Get the value of that radio button :

```
<?php $signi= $row['signi']; ?>
```

Then in HTML

```
<td align="left" valign="middle">
<input name="signi" type="radio" id="signi" value="S" <?php if($signi=='S'){ echo "checked=checked";}  ?>/> YES
<input name="signi" type="radio" id="signi" value="N" <?php if($signi=='N'){ echo "checked=checked";}  ?>/> No</td></td>
```

Comment: This question is two years old, and has an already accepted answer *very* similar to yours. Could you please elaborate on how your answer improves the existing ones?

Comment: Of course it similar like before but its much easy for new users. New user can little bit confuse of ? mark there in decision making so i have a simplified view

Answer (score 0):

you have to check database value first and then set checked property to checked if true

```
<input name="signi" type="radio" id="signi" value="S" <?php if($row["signi"]=="S"){echo "checked=\"checked\" "} ?> />`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.
when you fetch record from table you will be outputting the other data on the form. Let suppose `$row` is a php variable which contains the record.

```
if($row['checkboxfieldname'] == 'my required condition'){
?>  <input type = 'checkbox' value = '1' name = 'blahblah' checked> <?
}else{
?>  <input type = 'checkbox' value = '1' name = 'blahblah'> <?
}
```