# How to get checked radio button in edit blade in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, radio-button

I'm trying to get checked radio button in edit.

```
echo '<tr><td><input type=radio name="track_id"  value=".$id." {{ $ticket->track_id == '.$id.' ? 'checked' : ''}} >'.$title.'</td><td ><lable type=text name="tracks"  value="'.$id.'">'.$type.'</td></tr>';
```

This is the way that I'm using for getting checked radio button.

Here is my edit blade code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
    <table border="1">
    <tr><th ><strong>Title</strong></th><th><strong>Type</strong></th></tr>
<div style="margin-top: 5px" >

<?php $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'rp') or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$result = $conn->query("select track.id, track.track_title, track.track_type from track;");
//echo "<select name='tracks'>";
echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      unset($id, $title, $type);
      $id = $row['id'];
      $title = $row['track_title']; 
      $type = $row['track_type'];
      echo '<tr><td><input type=radio name="track_id"  value=".$id." {{ $ticket->track_id == '.$id.' ? 'checked' : ''}} >'.$title.'</td><td ><lable type=text name="tracks"  value="'.$id.'">'.$type.'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get checked radio button in edit page in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301164/how-to-get-checked-radio-button-in-edit-page-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this is written in php, not using blade templating. Your curly braces are being echoed as `{{` rather than escaping PHP. Also, `<label>` is spelled incorrectly, and does not have `type`, `name` and `value` attributes, and should be closed with `</label>`.

Either use PHP:

```
echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="track_id"  value="'.$id.'" id="track'.$id.'" '
. ( $ticket->track_id == $id ? 'checked' : '') . '>'.$title
.'</td><td><label for="track'.$id.'">'.$type.'</label></td></tr>';
```

or use blade...

```
@foreach($rows as $row)
@php $id = $row['id']; /* ... etc */ @endphp

<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="radio" name="track_id"  value="{{$id}}" {{ $ticket->track_id == $id ? 'checked' : '') }} id="track{{$id}}"> {{$title}}
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="track{{$id}}">{{$type}}</label>
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you. Its work fine now. (:

Comment: Can you please mark the answer “accepted”?