# Database and table for PHP form created but no data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a PHP enquiry form for users to give feedback and the data will be inserted into the database. Once the form is submitted, I want it to be redirected to homepage.

1. The database and database table were created successfully but, there's no data.
2. The error for the input using radio will echo after I click submit.
3. The form is not redirected to homepage (I think this is interconnected with problem number 1 & 2)

I do guess there's some issue with my code but, I don't have any idea on what to be fixed. Can someone help me to identify my mistakes? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "enquiry.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$name = $gender = $email = $feedback_types = $feedback = $date_time = "";
$name_err = $gender_err = $email_err = $feedback_types_err = $feedback_err = $date_time_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Check if name is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["name"]))){
        $name_err = "Please enter your name.";
    } else{
        $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    }
    
    // Check if gender is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["gender"]))){
        $gender_err = "Please select your gender.";
    } else{
        $gender = trim($_POST["gender"]);
    }
    
    // Check if email is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["email"]))){
        $email_err = "Please enter your email.";
    } else{
        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    }
    
    // Check if feedback types is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["feedback_types"]))){
        $feedback_types_err = "Please choose feedback types.";
    } else{
        $feedback_types = trim($_POST["feedback_types"]);
    }
    
    // Check if feedback is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["feedback"]))){
        $feedback_err = "Please enter your feedback.";
    } else{
        $feedback = trim($_POST["feedback"]);
    }
    
    // Check if date and time is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["date_time"]))){
        $date_time_err = "Please select date and time.";
    } else{
        $date_time = trim($_POST["date_time"]);
    }
    
    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($name_err) && empty($gender_err) && empty($email_err) && empty($feedback_types_err) && empty($feedback_err) && empty($date_time_err)){
        
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO enquiry (name, gender, email, feedback_types, feedback, date_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
            
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $param_name, $param_gender, $param_email, $param_feedback_types, $param_feedback, $param_date_time);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_name = $name;
            $param_gender = $gender;
            $param_email = $email;
            $param_feedback_types = $feedback_types;
            $param_feedback = $feedback;
            $param_date_time = $date_time;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: home.html");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        } else {
            echo "Error in preparing the statement: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Enquiry</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata">
<style>
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Inconsolata", sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Add a background color to the whole page -->
<div class="w3-sand w3-original colour w3-large">

<!-- Enquiry form-->
<div class="w3-container" id="about">
    <div class="w3-content" style="max-width: 700px; padding: 100px 0 100px 0;">
        <h5 class="w3-tag w3-wide"><span class="w3-tag w3-wide">FEEDBACKS/ENQUIRY</span></h5>
        <p>Submit your feedbacks or enquiry here!</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <p>
            <input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border form-control <?php echo (!empty($name_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $name_err; ?></span>
            </p>
            
            <p><span class="w3-tag">GENDER</span></p>
            
            <p>
            <input class="w3-padding-16 w3-border form-control <?php echo (!empty($gender_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $gender; ?>" type="radio" name="gender" required> Male
            <input class="w3-padding-16 w3-border form-control <?php echo (!empty($gender_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $gender; ?>" type="radio" name="gender" required> Female
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $gender_err; ?></span>
            </p>
            
            <p>
            <input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border form-control <?php echo (!empty($email_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $email_err; ?></span>
            </p>
            
            <p><span class="w3-tag">TYPES OF FEEDBACK</span></p>
            
            <p>
            <input class="w3-padding-16 w3-border form-control <?php echo (!empty($feedback_types_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $feedback_types; ?>" type="radio" name="feedback_types" required> Suggestion
            <input class="w3-padding-16 w3-border form-control <?php echo (!empty($feedback_types_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $feedback_types; ?>" type="radio" name="feedback_types" required> Complaint
            <input class="w3-padding-16 w3-border form-control <?php echo (!empty($feedback_types_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $feedback_types; ?>" type="radio" name="feedback_types" required> Enquiry
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $feedback_types_err; ?></span>
            </p>
            
            <p>
            <input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border form-control <?php echo (!empty($feedback_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $feedback; ?>" type="text" placeholder="Suggestion/Complaint/Enquiry" name="feedback" required>
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $feedback_err; ?></span>
            </p>
            
            <p>
            <input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border form-control <?php echo (!empty($date_time_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $date_time; ?>" type="datetime-local" placeholder="Date and Time" name="date_time" id="enter_date" onchange="CheckDate()" required>
            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $date_time_err; ?></span>
            </p>
            
            <script>
            function CheckDate() {
                var UserDate = document.getElementById("enter_date").value;
                var ToDate = new Date ();
                
                if (new Date(UserDate).getTime() <= ToDate.getTime()) {
                    alert("Booking date must past or equal to today's date");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            </script>
            
            <p><button class="w3-button w3-black" type="submit">SEND</button></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to read: [How do you debug PHP scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888/how-do-you-debug-php-scripts)

Comment: Don't guess...test and debug thoroughly instead. Line by line if necessary.

Comment: Start with what's in `var_dump($_POST);` after you submit the form, maybe

Comment: Radio buttons should have (usually unique) fixed values for each choice, and you compare the user-supplied value with the known value to determine the `checked` state: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14301202/231316